# Can't seem to get Boto's dynamodb.update_item to work

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm trying to use this Boto function,
But can't seem to get it right..
Any idea?
[Doc Link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item)

```
    tablename = 'name_table'
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName=tablename,
        Key={
            'name': 'Tony',
        },
        UpdateExpression="set name= :r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': 'Ralph',
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```

This are the errors I get :

```
Invalid type for parameter Key.name, value: set(['Tony', 0]), type: <type 'set'>, valid types: <type 'dict'>
```

I've tried to change the name from str to dict, 
So now I'm with this error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Where to go from here ?
Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key cannot be a dictionary.

```
     tablename = 'name_table'
     response = dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName=tablename,
        Key="name = :name",
        UpdateExpression="set name= :r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': 'Ralph',
            ':name': 'Tony'
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys in the API you referenced expect the values to be DynamoDB attributes, so the `Key` should be like this:

```
{
    'name': {
        'S': 'Tony'
    }
}
```

The `ExpressionAttributeValues` should be like this:

```
{
    ':r': {
        'S': 'Ralph'
    }
}
```

So the whole thing looks like this:

```py
    tablename = 'name_table'
    response = dynamodb.update_item(
        TableName=tablename,
        Key={
            'name': {
                'S': 'Tony'
             }
        },
        UpdateExpression="set name= :r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': {
                'S': 'Ralph'
            }
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```